# Oracle error - ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I'm getting an error message of "ORA-00936: missing expression" at the very start of line 2 at SELECT. I've looked over the data a countless number of times but can't seem to notice where i'm going wrong. I have a feeling it will be something extremely obvious! Any help would be great

```
Insert into EmployeeTable values
SELECT Name('Mrs','Alison','Smith'),
Address('23 Dart Grove', 'Edinburgh', 'EH10 5TT'),
Phone('01312125555', '07705623443','07907812345'),
'N1001',
ref(b),
'null',
'101',
'Head',
'50000',
'01-FEB-92'
from branchtable b
where b.bID = '901';
```

Comment: Try parentheses around your sub-select

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `VALUES`:

```
Insert into EmployeeTable 
SELECT ...
```

But I fear that this might not be the only issue...

Comment: That worked perfectly.there were no other issues... Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: Just curious. What is that `ref(b)`?

Comment: It's a reference between a table and a type